# how to grab a picture from a wikipedia API using JSON or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the API already, it is this:

```
"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=ronaldo"
```

how do I write a JavaScript/Jquery code to add this image to my page?

I tried this method, but it didn't work and I keep getting alert("Error")

```
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=ronaldo";

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:url,
    async:false,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data2){ // success doesn't call
        var x = data2.query.pages.thumbnail.original;
        console.log(x);

    },

    error:function(data2){alert("Error");} //alert("Error"); executes
});
```

Comment: the API works when I copy it to my browser on it's own, but the success function in my code's ajax is not executing, forgot to mention this, I get alert("Error");

Comment: Open the browser Console when you make the request. (Since  it works copied into your browser but not through Ajax) It is likely you'll see a red error about "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" If so, the easiest fix would be to create an API proxy that would run on your server. Let us know (edit your question) whether you get Access Control error, either way.

Comment: I do not really know how to create a server, I am still learning programming and front-end development, thanks for your answer

Comment: Understood. Just a couple things to be aware of: (1) If you are having a CORS policy issue, you may or may not be able to solve it on your end (you might not be authorized to access the server) and (2) Setting up a little test web server may be easier than you think, and will be helpful for a lot of things: http://ampps.com/download (3) Did you understand about getting the error from "the console"? (If not, check this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) - determining whether this really is a CORS issue is the next step in debugging.

Comment: @timster yes, I will definitely learn how to set up a server and do back end stuff, and I learned already how to use the console.thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. As mentioned [in the docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests) you need to use the `jsonp` `dataType` (i.e. `dataType:"jsonp",`)
2. Your traversal of the returned data is missing the page id. It should be: `data2.query.pages[66164].thumbnail.original`. Alternatively, loop through the returned pages if you don't have prior knowledge of the page id.

```js
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=ronaldo";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        var x = data.query.pages[66164].thumbnail.original;
        //  or, if you don't know the page id, you could use: 
        //  x = data.query.pages[Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0]].thumbnail.original
        document.write(x);
    },

    error: function(){ alert("Error"); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```